# Dataframe Plot Not Sorting

Tags: dataframe, plot

I apologize in advance as I have likely done something silly, but this is driving me nuts and I need a fresh set of eyes on the problem.  I have several flavors of data based on Zip code and I want my plots sorted by zip to make easy comparison.  My data looks like this

```
#   Zip Code    Location    City    Population  Avg. Population Age     National Rank
0   1.  78738   30.327510, -97.989040   Austin, Texas   2840    44.7    #2,611
1   2.  78734   30.376159, -97.946334   Austin, Texas   12925   40.6    #7,893
2   3.  78747   30.122470, -97.746210   Austin, Texas   5079    40.2    #8,682
3   4.  78737   30.177041, -97.956661   Austin, Texas   7100    40.0    #9,356
4   5.  78746   30.296951, -97.811647   Austin, Texas   26023   38.3    #14,001
```

if I run dtypes I get the following

```
0
#                       object
Zip Code                object
Location                object
City                    object
Population              object
Avg. Population Age    float64
National Rank           object
dtype: object
```

I convert the zip to an integert and Age to float and plot, but the x axix is not sorted

```
dAge['Avg. Population Age'] = dAge['Avg. Population Age'].astype(float)
dAge['Zip Code'] = dAge['Zip Code'].astype(int)
ax = dAge.plot.bar(x='Zip Code', y='Avg. Population Age', rot=0,figsize=(30,10),sort_columns=True)
```

[Resulting Plot, not sorted as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1cxx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the snippet. You have to sort your column first and store it so that your changes are reflected in your dataframe and then you can plot it.

[image: Sorted plot]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
data = {'Zip Code':[78738,78734,78747,78737,78746],'Avg. Population Age':[2840,12925,5079,7100,26023]}
dAge = pd.DataFrame(data)
new=dAge.sort_values('Zip Code').astype(int)
ax = new.plot.bar(x='Zip Code', y='Avg. Population Age', rot=0,figsize=(10,10))
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Ok, I am missing something then as what then does attribute sort_columns do?  Note in other data frames where the x-axis were zip code sort_columns did the trick.  Thanks

Comment: @Ncosgove sort_columns probably didnt work because your both the columns are integers and it doesnt know which column to sort so it didnt sort.  if my answer was helpful to you, please accept it as an answer